# DateTime without time / only data? It is possible in Prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I can in Prisma create columns without data, without time?

my model at the moment:

```
model modelName {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  lastNumber Int
}
```

Actual results:

```
2 2022-04-19 12:28:04.591+00    45
```

I want to generate records like this:

```
2 2022-04-19 45
```

Answer (score 24):

To store only the date portion you could use the native `@db.date` attribute.
That would just store the date and not store the time.

In your schema file you could update the model as below to just store the date portion:

```
model modelName {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now()) @db.Date
  lastNumber Int
}
```

Here's a reference to Prisma's PostgreSQL DateTime attribute: [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#postgresql-6)